# See Ant script generated by Netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ant, netbeans-7, glassfish-4

Please see the following webpage: https://netbeans.org/features/ide//build-tools.html.  It says: "You can therefore build and run your project outside the IDE exactly as it is built and run inside the IDE.".

I have spent hours trying to figure out how to see this Ant Script.  I have found suggestions such as setting: Toola\Options\Ant\Verbosity Level to Debug etc, but I see nothing.  How do I see the Ant script generated by Netbeans?

I am trying to see what Netbeans generates when I run the app, so that I can try to run the app externally to Netbeans.  It is a J2EE app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for build.xml
But J2EE apps must be run inside a webserver such as Tomcat.
You can't run them from the command prompt.

Comment: How do you run an Enterprise Application Client.  This is what I am trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793208/run-enterprise-application-client-outside-netbeans

Comment: Usually a .WAR file is generated which you upload to the webserver.  Download and install http://tomcat.apache.org/ It will take a while to figure it out.  You need to run it and bring up the manager webpage (http://localhost:8080/manager/html) where you can upload your WAR files.  Then the J2EE app will be available on the website (http://localhost:8080/myapp)

Comment: But this is an application client - not a web app.  How do I run an enterprise app client externally to netbeans?

Comment: 1) Tomcat is a web container - it cannot run full Java EE profile.

2) It is possible - just a matter to find how (I'm not sure yet...)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the Java EE tutorial regarding that topic: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhpu.html#gkhol

In case you would decide to use Maven, then the newer version can be more applicable: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/usingexamples.htm#GFIUD

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain how this answers my question? I am trying to run an application client (enterprise application client) outside netbeans.  I cannot believe how difficult it is to find any information whatsoever on the subject.  Every single example shows how to run in netbeans only.

Comment: Those documents describe how to run the app with ant and maven outside NetBeans - just look there.

Hmmmm... now you say that's a client? Before you've said it's a Java EE app...

Comment: It is a java application client on pc A that uses glassfish enterprise beans on server B.  The application works in netbeans.  I am trying to figure out how to use it outside netbeans.  Does that make sense?

Comment: See this as an example: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html.  Main.java is an application client rather than a web client that uses ejbs.

Comment: If I remember correctly, `ant run` does the job. Did you try that?

BTW, each time you run the app from NetBeans, you can see the (ant) command used in the Output window.

Comment: Ant run app.jar.  Is that what you mean? I cant see it being that simple! I think appclient.bat and gf-client.jar play a part somewhere.

Comment: No, just `ant run`. Please check the Output window in Netbeans for the exact command.

Comment: I guess the command has to be run in the same directory as build.xml? Where is build.xml? I am a .net developer trying to get up to speed with java in my spare time.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, in the same dir - please search for it inside your project structure. `find . -name build.xml` on Linux.

Comment: Thanks.  I will try this tomorrow and then report back marking the answer if necessary.  Is it really that simple? Ant run build.xml ? Would it work on a pc without glassfish ie using remote glassfish with remote interface?